# Load more in bottom UITableView using NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I want to load more cells when user in the last cell. I use CoreData and I get data from it. I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22732057/4773976) answer to do what I want, but it didn't work. What problem can be there? Also I have one more question. I don't know why working only first implementation.

> First implementation

```
var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController {
    let moc = DatabaseController.sharedInstance.managedObjectContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Coctail", inManagedObjectContext: moc)

    fetchRequest.entity = entity
    fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 10
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]

    let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
                                                               managedObjectContext: moc,
                                                               sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
                                                               cacheName: nil)
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self

    do {
        try aFetchedResultsController.performFetch()
    } catch {
        fatalError("\(error)")
    }
    return aFetchedResultsController
}
```

> Second Implementation

```
func initilizeFetchedResultsController() {
    let moc = DatabaseController.sharedInstance.managedObjectContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Coctail", inManagedObjectContext: moc)

    fetchRequest.entity = entity
    fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 10
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]

    let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
                                                               managedObjectContext: moc,
                                                               sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
                                                               cacheName: nil)
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self

    do {
        try aFetchedResultsController.performFetch()
    } catch {
        fatalError("\(error)")
    }
    fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell why the first solution but the second doesn't without seeing the other code that would have used the `fetchedResultsController` or called `initilizeFetchedResultsController()`.

The reason you're not getting more data is that you've hardcoded your `fetchLimit` to 10.  No matter what you do, you'll only ever get 10 results.

You'll need to change the fetchLimit to get more data.  Check out this answer -- it is similar to what you'll need to do:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/6786931/5605379

Comment: I do it like in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20269474/uitableview-load-more-when-scrolling-to-bottom-like-facebook-application/22732057#22732057) and I chanced fetchLimit